# Orbit hit animation pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I need help with orbit hit animation in pygame.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJ9Cf.jpg)

Like in the picture. The crosshair is a square. The purple dot is a staring point and yellow dot is a ending point. I want the animation to go from purple dot to yellow dot.

Example from terraria. great game by the way https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/terraria_gamepedia/images/d/dc/Night%27s_Edge_%28demo%29.gif/revision/latest?cb=20211203212949

Comment: Could you show some code ? What you tried ? Why it doesn't work ? etc. Impossible to help without this.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/284237/354577)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood your problem as *How to orbit a point around an origin that follows the mouse cursor*

Assuming that is correct, we know from basic trigonometry that we can get a point around a circle using *cos* and *sin* in such a fashion

```
p = (x, y)
p.x = cos(a)
p.y = sin(a)
```

where `a` is the angle between the point and the x-axis. We can then scale the components to change the radius of the circle, like so

```
p.x *= r
p.y *= r
```

where `r` is the radius. Then the angle can be calculated using the *atan2* function, which takes in two coordinates,
`x` and `y`, and calculated the angle relative to the origin.

[image]

*Image taken from https://planetcalc.com/7955/*

Where *x* and *y* is the position of the cursor translated by the inverse of the position of the origin (your character). The entire ordeal boils down to this,

```
a = atan2((my-oy)/(mx-ox))
p.x = cos(a) * r
p.y = sin(a) * r
```

where `mx`,`my` is the position of the cursor, `ox`,`oy` is the position of the origin, and `r` is the radius of the circle.

If you want to *animate* the angle over time, you can use a target variable and an interpolated variable that approaches the target value over time. Or use a library for it.